# Assign cursor values to sequential variables PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, cursor

I have some variables that I would like to assign values based on a cursor in PL/SQL.
the variables are variable_1, variable_2, variable_3.

```
 FOR cursor_name IN
  (SELECT            *
  FROM
    (select acct_id from dual)
  LOOP
//Exit when i > 3
     variable_i := acct_id;
i:= i+1;
  END LOOP;
```

Thanks

Comment: It is really unclear, what you are trying to ask, could you please elaborate on your question

Answer (score 0):

When you go through a cursor with a FOR loop you get a record with all the fields in the query, in your case the record is named 'cursor_name'. :

```
FOR cursor_name IN (SELECT acct_id FROM dual) LOOP
  //Exit when i > 3
  variable_i := cursor_name.acct_id;
  i:= i+1;
END LOOP;
```